# Problems with creating combined image view / camera view window using EmguCV & Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, emgucv

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to create a window with list of images and large image view box. If user points at one of the images in the list, imagebox should display it, otherwise it should display live feed from a webcam.

I'm trying to achieve that by using ImageGrabbed event of EmguCV.Capture, and a field that stores index of the currently viewed image. Camera feed works alright, however, when I move the mouse over listbox, image view merely stops updating. It stays stuck at the last frame it saw, and doesn't display the image I'm pointing at. I've checked that the list has images in it, that index is correct, and that image coming from the camera is different from ones saved in the list. Also, same behavior happens when I use vanila PictureBox.

See the code (stripped of extra parts) below.

Initialization:

```
int ViewedFrame = -1;
var Frames = new List<Image<Rgb, byte>>();
// This list will have some images added to it along the way.
// They will be displayed in a custom drawn ListBox bound to the list.
Camera = new Emgu.CV.Capture(cameraid);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
Camera.ImageGrabbed += UpdateCamera;
Camera.Start();
```

Frame capture:

```
private void UpdateCamera(object sender, System.EventArgs ev)
{
    if (ViewedFrame == -1)
        Preview.Image = Camera.RetrieveBgrFrame();
    else
        // !!! this line has no apparent effect, image in the ImageBox is still the same
        Preview.Image = Frames[ViewedFrame]; 
}
```

Mouse handling:

```
private void FrameList_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = FrameList.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index == ListBox.NoMatches)
       ViewedFrame = -1;
    else if (index != ViewedFrame)
    {
        ViewedFrame = index;
    }
}

private void FrameList_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewedFrame = -1;
}
```

UPD: I tried adding `Preview.Update()` and `Preview.Refresh()` into the same branch as Frames[ViewedFrame], and after the conditional operator. In first case it doesn't have any effect. In second case nothing is shown at all. In case the ImageBox can't keep up updating itself, I enabled doublebuffering, but that didn't help either. Moreover, after I hover the mouse over an image in the list, the camera stream breaks too. The code above is the only one that's somewhat working.

Comment: Do you have 'Preview.Update();' immediately after setting the Image property?

Comment: Updated the question. In short, it gets worse.

Comment: By chance if the 'Camera.RetrieveBgrFrame();' is not called within that function, then maybe the camera will not try to capture any more frames and then will not call the UpdateCamera() event.   Try setting it to grab the frame anyways, but stuffing it into an unused image variable that is set to null afterwards (For better GC cleanup)

Comment: Don, UpdateCamera() is called (just logged its calls, all seems fine). I narrowed it down to a specific line that's not working, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Which specific line?

Comment: As noted in the question itself, it's `Preview.Image = Frames[ViewedFrame]; ` assignment. I checked step-by-step, it's actually being called - just to no visible effect, and no amount of Update()'s or Refresh()'es help. The similar line above works just fine when conditions for it to run are met.